# Need help getting camera to follow instantiated GameObject (player)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working on a multiplayer game in Unity3D. Like many others, I've got some serious issues getting the camera to follow the player. In a normal game, you simply make the camera object a child of the player object to make it follow the player. In multiplayer, this is not an option as players need to spawn (prefab).

So instead you need to use C# to make the camera follow the player using the player objects transform position. This is what I've tried:

```
public Transform target;
public float smoothing = 5f;

Vector3 offset;

public GameObject playerPrefab;

private void SpawnPlayer()
{
    Network.Instantiate(playerPrefab, Vector3.up * 5, Quaternion.identity, 0);
    offset = transform.position - target.position;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Ofcourse I've assigned the player prefab to target. So when the game starts, the cameras position is transformed to the players position. But after that, it refuses to follow the player. It just sits there.

So I've started debugging this with:

```
Debug.log(target.position);
```

It returns the starting location of the player, but doesn't get updated as the player moves around. It remains the same. So that's obviously the reason the camera won't follow the player.

The question is: Why doesn't the player position get updated? Or most likely it does, but the script doesn't see it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure but you seem to instantiate the player via the Instantiate method. But target is not assigned the transform of the player. What is target?

Comment: @fafase Target is assigned inside Unity by dragging the player prefab towards it. You can't see that in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comments,here is your problem.

When you drag the prefab you assign the transform of the prefab. The player is actually an instance of the prefab (a clone) but not the prefab itself.

You need to create the new object and assign its transform to it.

```
GameObject player = (GameObject)Network.Instantiate(playerPrefab, Vector3.up * 5, Quaternion.identity, 0);
target = player.transform;
offset = transform.position - target.position;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve it either. Just getting blank screen in game and inside the editor camera still isn't moving with the player.

Comment: Is that script attached to the camera?

Comment: Yes. Seems this script is causing the camera to drop down beneath the ground with the player object. After that it just rests there

Comment: Nvm. Solved it. Forgot to add the new gameobject to the global scope so it wouldn't update it xD Thanks a lot m8! You saved me from a lot of frustration!

Comment: Mind if I ask your help with one last thing? It seems like Unity doesn't really like multiple cameras. As in the other player sees his camera jump between players every update. Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: I can't say, using the project you linked, I can only session to run. The second one gets stuck at the UI.